# Why does activator hang when loading existing project in UI mode?

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I'm migrating a project from terminal-based SBT to [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt). It was my understanding that this would be a seamless process as the Typesafe Activator is using SBT underneath.

However, every time I try to load my existing project the Typesafe Activator console window displays *"Compiling project definition..."*. Nothing else happens, no matter how long I wait. When I try to run the project only using SBT, everything works as before.

Comment: What commands do you execute and how/where - command line or browser? Does `activator compile` work? What about just `activator` and then `compile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`activator shell` command should work anytime sbt does but `activator ui` (UI mode) has limitations that will keep it from working with many projects for now.

See [Typesafe Activator - An Update and Roadmap Preview](http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-activator---an-update-and-roadmap-preview) for the long story.